# Spring Data Specification filtering with Set<String> over String

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

Suppose that I have a table with a column `categories` where values are separated by comma. I make a custom converter that accepts raw string from the database and returns `Set<String>`. Here is the entity

```java
@Entity
public MyEntity {
    @Convert(converter = StringToSetConverter.class)
    private Set<String> categories;
}
```

Now I want to filter the entities by categories presence. Logic tells me that I cannot use `in` predicate, because the actual value in the database is a raw string.

Maybe this approach is acceptable

```java
myEntityRepository.findAll((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> 
  criteriaBuilder.like(
    criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("categories").as(String.class))
    pattern.toLowerCase()
  )
);
```

Perhaps there is a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: This question is opinion-based. I think your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is fine. Depending on the database you are using, you could use array types on the database though and use array contains functions instead to implement these checks, but if what you have now works for you, there is no need to change that.